# Get variable value from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to save some variables for future reference so I declared a class `Container.cs`

```
public class Container
{
    public static String verifierCode;
}
```

and then I have my `HomeController.cs` where I update the Container's variables values:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ValidateTwitterAuth()
    {
        Container.verifierCode = Request.Query.ElementAt(2).Value;
        //do some stuff
    }
    public String sendTweet(String NewTweet)
    {
        var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(Container.verifierCode, Container.authorizationId);
        var user = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser(userCreds);
        user.PublishTweet(NewTweet);
        return "sent!";
    }
}
```

It gets updated in the `ValidateTwitterAuth` with the specific values but when the `sendTweet` method is called the `Container.verifierCode` is null.
I obviously tried to debug it but if I add the variable to quickwatch i get that

> error CS0103: The name 'Container' does not exist in current context

Also, both the class and the container are in the same namespace. 
Any idea/tip why this is happening? I am just trying to declare a global variable which I can access from other classes/controllers.

I apologise if this may sound like a beginner question but I'm just starting to get my hands on asp.net

EDIT: From the answers, my way of handling with the problem was wrong. Therefore I installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` NuGet Package and used it like this:

```
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("verifierCode", Request.Query.ElementAt(2).Value);
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("authorizationId", Request.Query.ElementAt(0).Value);
```

and now it works. Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: Remove `static`

Comment: @BenderBending Can you expand on what that will do to resolve the issue?

Comment: You need to store this data into session.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Static generally means that it can not be instanced, and is sealed. I'm not very well versed on the specifics though.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing your own custom Container class instead of a native .NET Container class like System.ComponentModel.Container?

Comment: @BenderBending So that's a "no".

Comment: Anyway, this is a compiler error that is all about referencing and order. Please update your sample code with all relevant information about the specific code-structures like  assemblies, namspaces and separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store this data into session instead of class.as per below example

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ValidateTwitterAuth()
        {
            Session["verifierCode"] = Request.Query.ElementAt(2).Value;
            //do some stuff
        }
        public String sendTweet(String NewTweet)
        {
            var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(Session["verifierCode"], Container.authorizationId);
            var user = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser(userCreds);
            user.PublishTweet(NewTweet);
            return "sent!";
        }
    }
```

i have just change only verify code

Comment: This works, however, this is NOT an answer to the problem, mmore a workaround (and not a very good one IMHO)

Comment: Yes, Caspar, i agree with you this work but this is not a good solution but you need to design your architect as your requirement.